# Why does my script end only after I ^D it?

Tags: bash, shell, stdin

I have a script that takes in a youtube link and extracts the available resolutions of that video to a "res.txt" file using youtube-dl. The res.txt file contains the required output, but is shown only after i press ^D. Could someone tell me why does my script get stuck?

```
#!/bin/bash
youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVv_aSTVpyI > info.txt
echo Start
cat > res.txt
for i in '144p' '240p' '360p' '480p' '720p' '1080p' '1440p' '2160p' ; do
    while read p ; do
        if [[ "$p" == *"$i"* ]] ; then
            echo "$i" >> res.txt
            break
        fi
    done < info.txt
done 
echo "done"
a=1
sed -i '1d' res.txt
echo "Please Type required resolution: "
while read p ; do
     echo -n $a
     echo -n ")"
     echo $p
     a=$((a+1))
done < res.txt
read reso
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=$reso]+bestaudio' $link
```

Comment: `cat > res.txt` What does that line do?

Comment: @Shawn: It reads standard input until CTRL-D is pressed. Perhaps OP wanted to use `echo > res.txt` (or even just `> res.txt`) to clear existing contents of the file.

Comment: @user000001 I was hoping OP would figure that out themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be shorter and efficient with:

```sh
youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVv_aSTVpyI |
  grep -oE '(144|240|360|480|720|1080|1440|2160)p' |
    sort -u > res.txt
```

- `grep -oE`: Extracts lines matching the Extended RegEx, and prints only the matching part.
- `sort -u`: Sorts the lines and remove duplicates.

#### With JSON processing

Alternatively, if you want to reliably extract `width` and `height` meta-data, `youtube-dl` can produce a JSON data-set with the `-j` option switch, to parse it with `jq`:

```sh
youtube-dl -j https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVv_aSTVpyI |
  jq -r  '[ .formats| .[] | select(.width != null) | [.width,.height] ] | unique | .[] | @tsv'
```

#### Featured dialog menu resolution selection and download

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[[ $# -eq 1 ]] || exit 2

# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVv_aSTVpyI

link="$1"

declare -a res
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a res < <(
youtube-dl -j "$link" |
  jq '[.formats|.[]|select(.width!=null)|[.width,.height]]|unique|.[]|@sh'
)

declare -a options=()
for i in "${!res[@]}"; do
  read -r width height <<<"${res[i]}"
  options+=("$i" "$width×$height")
done

{
  choice=$(
    dialog \
      --clear \
      --backtitle "youtube-dl $link" \
      --title '[ V I D E O - R E S O L U T I O N ]' \
      --menu 'Select the video resolution' 0 0 "${#options[@]}" "${options[@]}" \
      1>&3 2>&1
  )
} 3>&1 || exit

read -r width height <<<"${res[choice]}"
printf -v format 'bestvideo[height<=%d]+bestaudio' "$height"
youtube-dl -f "$format" "$link"
```

Comment: thanks for that, certainly much quicker. do you know a lot about youtube-dl? do you know how i can extract the video height and width to the text file instead of the standard resolutions?

Comment: @SanjayRao You can have `youtube-dl` output a JSON data-set with `-j` and process this JSON with `jq` as: `youtube-dl -j https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVv_aSTVpyI | jq -r  '.formats| .[] | select(.width != null) | [.width,.height] | @tsv' | sort -u` to produce a tab delimited list of width and height.